# globalSetup to reference baseUrl from playwright.config

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

Im currently using a global-setup.ts file to load a url via playwright.

`await page.goto('https://test1.com/');`

I am also doing extra code inside here and storing the state of my object (All works as expected)

My playwright.config.ts file references the globalsetup and this all works as expected.

In my Config file I also set baseUrl however, I am struggling on a way to get the baseUrl passed to my global-setup.ts file instead of hardcoding it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Inside your global setup, you can access the `baseURL` like that:

```
import { FullConfig } from '@playwright/test';

async function globalSetup(config: FullConfig) {
  console.log(config.projects[0].use.baseURL);
}

export default globalSetup
```

See here: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testconfig/

Comment: Hi Max. I dont think this will work. Im using multiple projects and this is only taking the first projects url. Is there a way of me being able to pass the project I have already selected?

Comment: globalSetup will only run a single time before all the tests run. There is no globalSetup yet for projects. If you want different globalSetups per project you for now need to create multiple playwright config files.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to store/read baseUrl is, to store it as an environment variable. You can store as many variables(or URLs in your case) and secrets and it can be created per environment, such as dev.env, qa.env etc.
You can [read env vars](https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs/) by using dotenv package from anywhere in the project.

```js
require('dotenv').config();

process.env.BASE_URL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, after reading several documents I understood that the best place to set and build your baseURL is not in the `globalSetup.js` file but in the first lines of the `playwright.config.js` file.

```
/* playwright.config.js file */

const { defineConfig, devices } = require('@playwright/test');
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import environments from './config/environments.json';

try {
  // Read env file only if not in CI
  if (!process.env.CI) {
      dotenv.config({
          path: '.env',
          override: true
      });
      // Creating a new BASE_URL environment variable
      process.env.BASE_URL = environments[process.env.ENVIRONMENT] || environments.local }`,
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error loading environment variables:", error);
}


module.exports = defineConfig({
  use: {
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL <-- Here we use our new env var
  ...
})
```

My `environment.json` file looks like this:

```
{
    "local": "http://localhost:3000",
    "dev": "https://dev.mypage.com",
    "qa": "https://qa.mypage.com",
    "staging": "https://staging.mypage.com",
    "prod": "https://mypage.com"
}
```

and my `.env` file looks like this:

```
ENVIRONMENT = "dev"
USERNAME = "myname"
PASSWORD = "mypassword"
```

With all these lines in place, then you can simple use the baseURL or the new BASE_URL env variable wherever you need:

`globalSetup.js` file:

```
import { FullConfig } from '@playwright/test';

async function globalSetup(config: FullConfig) {
    await page.goto(process.env.BASE_URL);
}

export default globalSetup
```

---

Also as extra information, remember that in the globalSetup file we can only read this info from the `config` parameter:

```
{
  configFile: '/Users/lopeze3/git/wapo/arc-subs-ui/packages/arc-subs-playwright/playwright.config.js',
  rootDir: '/Users/lopeze3/git/wapo/arc-subs-ui/packages/arc-subs-playwright/tests',
  forbidOnly: false,
  fullyParallel: false,
  globalSetup: '/Users/lopeze3/git/wapo/arc-subs-ui/packages/arc-subs-playwright/config/global-setup.js',
  globalTeardown: '/Users/lopeze3/git/wapo/arc-subs-ui/packages/arc-subs-playwright/config/global-teardown.js',
  globalTimeout: 0,
  grep: /.*/,
  grepInvert: null,
  maxFailures: 0,
  metadata: {},
  preserveOutput: 'always',
  reporter: [ [ 'list', undefined ], [ 'html', [Object] ] ],
  reportSlowTests: { max: 5, threshold: 15000 },
  quiet: false,
  projects: [],
  shard: null,
  updateSnapshots: 'missing',
  version: '1.42.1',
  workers: 6,
  webServer: null,[Symbol(configInternalSymbol)]: FullConfigInternal {}
}
```

So, as you can see the `baseURL` is not one of those values we can access inside our globalSetup file.